# What does "if (!''.replace(/^/, String))" do?

Tags: javascript, regex

When browsing minified Javascript code, I often see the following statement:

```
if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
    // ...
}
```

What does this do? It seems that any ECMA-compliant JS interpreter will replace the beginning of the string with `String('')`, which still results in an empty string, whose negation is `true`.

In what circumstances will the behavior be different?

Comment: out of curiosity, where did you see it?

Comment: Five search results: [search for `(!''.replace(/^/, String))` with SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%28!%27%27.replace%28%2F^%2F%2C+String%29%29)

Comment: This code occurs in the [dean.edwards.name/packer/](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) JS compressor when you check “Base62 encode”. Try packing `alert("example");` and look at the output.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Stack Overflow supports symbols out of the box, just quote it: ["(!''.replace(/^/, String))"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%28!%27%27.replace%28/%5E/,%20String%29%29%22)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seems to be coming from packers, like for exemple [Dean Edwards javascript packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/)

So, let's download the code and see what it says ...

```
// code-snippet inserted into the unpacker to speed up decoding
const JSFUNCTION_decodeBody =
//_decode = function() {
// does the browser support String.replace where the
//  replacement value is a function?

'    if (!\'\'.replace(/^/, String)) {
        // decode all the values we need
        while ($count--) {
            $decode[$encode($count)] = $keywords[$count] || $encode($count);
        }
        // global replacement function
        $keywords = [function ($encoded) {return $decode[$encoded]}];
        // generic match
        $encode = function () {return \'\\\\w+\'};
        // reset the loop counter -  we are now doing a global replace
        $count = 1;
    }
';
```

It seems to check if the current browsers supports callbacks as the second argument to `replace()`, and if yes takes advantage of that to speed things up.

As a remainder, `String` in javascript is a function, the one you use when you do `var foo = String('bar');`, although you probably rarely use that syntax if ever.

Comment: This is probably very old since it is supported since explorer 7 and in explorer 5 quirks mode

Comment: @raam86 Dean Edwards packer dates from before 2004 according to the source code (which probably means even earlier than that in reality).

Answer (score 3):

This can be used to check if the `String` function wasn't overwritten by a careless developer.

In JavaScript nothing is immutable so:

```
!''.replace(/^/, String)
true //console prints
String
function String() { [native code] } //console prints
String()
"" //console prints
String = "eDSF"
"eDSF" //console prints
String() 
TypeError: string is not a function //console prints
!''.replace(/^/, String)
false //console prints
```

#### Of course this isn't what most people use it for.

Github shows [1053](https://github.com/search?q=%22if%20%28!%27%27.replace%28/%5E/,%20String%29%29%20%22&type=Code&s=indexed) examples with the same use.

```
   // code-snippet inserted into the unpacker to speed up decoding
    var _decode = function() {
        // does the browser support String.replace where the
        //  replacement value is a function?
        if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
            // decode all the values we need
            while ($count--) $decode[$encode($count)] = $keywords[$count] || $encode($count);
           //...code code 
        }
    };
```

Comment: There are lots of values you can assign to `String` that will make the expression as a whole still evaluate to `true`, so this is unfortunately not it.

Comment: Replacing 1 and true gives same behavior  and `function(){console.log("DSF")}`

Comment: Actually, if you were to interpret it that way; it only checks if `String` is still a function, and that this function when passed an empty string as argument still returns an empty string. Not that useful, since plenty of legitimate function would do that and not have anything to do with the original String.